# Writing data to multiple folders in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write `A` in multiple folders, namely, `1,2,3,4,5` with file name `A.txt`. But I am getting an error. How do I fix it?

```
import os

Runs=5

def function(run):
    from scipy.stats import truncnorm
    import numpy as np
    import csv 
    
    parent_folder = str(run + 1)
    os.mkdir(parent_folder)

    A=3


    ######################################

    with open(os.path.join(parent_folder, rf"A.txt"), 'w+') as f: 
        
        #print("A =",[A])
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(A)
     


for x in range(Runs):
    function(x)
```

The error is

```
in function
    writer.writerow(A)

Error: iterable expected, not int
```

Comment: The line `print("A =",[A])` is a subtle lie to yourself. You're printing `[A]` as a list, but using it as a scalar. The error tells you everything you need to know

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary imports (see [mcve], with emphasis on "minimal"). I also recommend not doing imports inside your function unless you have a really solid business case for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a dearth of answers explaining what the actual problem is among the possible duplicates on this site, so here goes.

[`csv.csvwriter.writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) expects an iterable of elements that represents a row of data. It can't and won't guess that a single element should be treated specially (what the error is telling you). If you try to pass in something that's only accidentally an iterable, such as a string, each character will be treated as a separate element. To correctly write a row, wrap it in an iterable, such as a list, tuple, or even generator:

```
[A]
(A,)
(A for _ in range(1))
```

A similar thing happens with [`csv.csvwriter.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows). The function expects an iterable of rows, which are themselves iterables. A nested list or tuple will do, but you can't pass in scalars or single-level iterables. In the latter case, iterating over scalar elements and attempting to treat them as rows will result in the same error as you saw, for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The `writer.writerow` expects an iterable, not an integer, because a CSV row can have multiple values (one for each column).

You can fix it by putting `A` inside a list:

```py
writer.writerow([A])
```

More information on the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow

Comment: Only if your string has one character. In the general case, this is bad advice

Comment: @MadPhysicist The code would work with multiple characters, but each one would be placed as a different value for the row. I've adjusted the text to make it more clear what is happening.